# How do I use Scanner to read in a series of Strings from the keyboard, all on one line, and concatenate them

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, concatenation

How do I use Scanner to read in a series of Strings from the keyboard, all on one line, and concatenate them.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exam12Practice {

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      String words="";
      System.out.println("enter a word");
      while(input.hasNext())
      {
         words = words.concat(input.next());
      }

      System.out.println(words);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code already does what you are asking. To get it to work

```
Type in your words
Press Enter
Press CTRL-Z (^D on *nix systems)
```

**Some points to note:**

`input.hasNext()` will always return true for `STDIN` so just pressing Enter on its own won't work.

You could have used `input.readLine()` and split the words for your exercise.

Most people would probably prefer to use `StringBuilder` because of the improved performance it provides over `String.concat`.